# How to display the content of a <div> inside another <div> in another page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages.

*Index.html*

```html
<div id="source">
    Contenido de Usuario
</div>

<input type="button" id="export" value="Export Data">
```

*Users.html*

```html
<div id="target">
</div>
```

How to display the content of the source `<div>` element in *Index.html* inside the target `<div>` element in *Users.html* with JavaScript?

Comment: The usual way to do this is with IFRAME.

Comment: If they're in the same domain, `Users.html` can use AJAX to fetch the contents of `Index.html`. Parse that into a DOM, get the `source` DIV and append that to the `target` DIV.

Comment: Yes, Those are in the same domain of de same project.

Comment: Please show what you tried. Like I said, you can read one page from another page using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) API.

*Index.html*

```html
<div id="source">
    Contenido de Usuario
</div>
```

*Users.html*

```html
<div id="target">
    <!-- content will be inserted here -->
</div>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        fetch("Index.html")
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Error with response.");
                }
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(html => {
                let parser = new DOMParser();
                let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
                let sourceContent = doc.getElementById("source").textContent;
                document.getElementById("target").textContent = sourceContent;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error fetching content:", error);
            });
    };
</script>
```

You may need to sanitize the HTML content first as well, just to make sure it's safe to append using, for example, [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).

Answer (score 0):

You make no mention of the **size** of this source or what **kind** of data it is… both of which are very important in making an informed decision.

Anyway, assuming the size is less than 2.5MB and the data is plain text with nothing special in there, I guess you can...

In *Index.html*

```
<body onload="sessionStorage.setItem('source',source.textContent);">
```

In *Users.html*

```
<body onload="target.textContent=sessionStorage.getItem('source');">
```

**NB**: Untested pseudo-code suggestion.

**Update**: So an hour later you decide to introduce a button into the equation eh... not very smart!

Comment: sorry, I forget it.